# Data Modelling of System With Constraints

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to create an Entity-Relationship Diagram but I have lost track of it.

**Definition og assignment:** Make an Entity/Relationship Diagram for the system, for example the entities: *Publication*, *Author*, *Publisher*, *Editor* and *other entities* needed.

I also have a number of **features/considerations** that I need to take into account: 
**1.** The system must keep track of the status of all publication projects.

**2.** The status of a publication project is at any time one and only one of the
following: *Proposal*, *Accepted*, *Abandoned*, *Completed*, or *Other*.

**3.** A publication project can be of two types; *book* or *article*.

**4.** When an author proposes a publication, *the title*, *topic*, *date*, *planned completion date*, and the *email address* of the lead author is recorded. Furthermore, an editor and a publisher is connected to the project.

**5.** A publication may have one or multiple authors, one author is lead author,
other authors are co-authors.

**6.** A publication may have only one publisher (i.e. a publishing company) and
only one editor connected.

This was my first idea:
[First interpretation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsMNg.jpg)

However, I am confused whether Lead Author and Co-Author should have their own tables, whether the Author table should have the foreign key of the Publication table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this.

Can you tell me if this is what you have in head ?

[image]

We have the following table
(only describing the key here except for PUBLICATION_AUTHOR who need to be more detailed)

```
PUBSTATE(ID)
PUBTYPE(ID)
PUBLICATION(ID)
AUTHOR(ID)
EDITOR(ID)
PUBLISHER(ID)
EDITOR(ID)
PUBLICATION_STATE(PUBSTATE.ID, PUBLICATION.ID)
PUBLICATION_TYPE(PUBTYPE.ID, PUBLICATION.ID)
PUBLICATION_AUTHOR(PUBLICATION.ID, AUTHOR.ID, MAINAUTHOR)
PUBLICATION_PUBLISHER(PUBLICATION.ID, PUBLISHER.ID)
PUBLICATION_EDITOR(PUBLICATION.ID, EDITOR.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the same author can have a different role (co-author, lead author, [contributor](https://www.enago.com/academy/difference-contributor-and-co-author/)...) in different publications. So you need an association entity like "authorship" to group these relations.

[image]